# Rails Mailer: send emails to recipients based on matching criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have managed to configure my ActionMailer to send emails to recipients based on a new 'submission'. However, the way my app works is that it takes the submissions 'Desired Location' field and matches it up to the 'Company Business location' field in another model called Agents to give an index view that is matched by location depending on user. i.e if i submit a submission with a location of london, then only agents with a location of london will be able to see it. Which brings me to my emails, is there anyway to create a mailer that works in the same way? So only send emails to agents who match the desired location of the submission?

Mailer

```
class NewSubmissionMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def submission_email(submission)
    @submission = submission
    mail(to: @submission.Email, subject: 'Welcome to Ottom8')
  end

end
```

Submissions Controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @submission.save

    # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save       
    NewSubmissionMailer.submission_email(@submission).deliver_now
```

Code to match both models

```
def index
  @submissions = Submission.where(:Desired_Location => current_agent.Company_Business_Location)
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @submission.save
    # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
    NewSubmissionMailer.submission_email(@submission).deliver_now

    # Send emails to matching agents
    NewSubmissionMailer.matching_agents_email(@submission).deliver_now
```

and then in the mailer `::matching_agents_email`:

```
def matching_agents_email(submission) 
  @submission = submission
  agents = Agent.where(:Company_Business_Location => @submission.Desired_Location)
  mail(to: agents.pluck(:email) # ... Rest of email logic. )
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for getting back to me, it works! One slight tweak to add for any one viewing is the matching_agents_email method in the mailer needed an instance variable for submissions to pass Desired_Location through. e.g def matching_agents_email (submission) @submission = submission # followed by the rest of the code above..

Comment: @WernerAdewole I added the explicit instance variable assignment to avoid any future confusion.